# Como chamar métodos de forma que tenham um delay?

Tags: c#, algoritmo, async, asynctask, task

Tenho uma classe:

```
public class Robo {
    public async Task Ligar() {
        /*
         * Algo que pode demorar ou nao depende do status do robo
         * */
    }
}
public class TesteRobo {
    public void Main() {
            List < Robo > robos = new List < Robo > ();

            foreach(var item in robos) {
                    item.Ligar();
                    /**
                 * não posso ligar todos no mesmo instante, para não pesar no processamento
                 * preciso que após o primeiro ser executado seja esperado um tempo, por exemplo 30 segundos
                 * para poder chamar o próximo
                 * /
            }
        }
}
```

Gostaria de saber uma alternativa para não usar `Thread.Sleep()`?

**É possível substituir o `"for"` pelo `Task.Run` com `lambda` e `linq`?**

Grato

Bem, só informando resolvi desse modo:

```
class Robot
{
    private readonly string name;
    public string Name { get { return this.name; } }

    public Robot(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public void Ligar()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Robo: {name} ligando");
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Robo: {name}  iniciando");
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"Robo: {name} ligando");

    }
}

 private static void DoWorkRobots()
    {
        List<Robot> robots = new List<Robot>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            Robot robot = new Robot("Robo " + i);
            robots.Add(robot);
        }

        foreach (var item in robots)
        {
            var t = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{item.Name} - Antes de ligar - {DateTime.Now}");
                item.Ligar();
                Console.WriteLine($"{item.Name} - Depois de ligar - {DateTime.Now}");
                Thread.Sleep(4000);
            });
            t.Wait(2000);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Aguarda 5 segundos");

        Thread.Sleep(5000);

        Console.WriteLine("Terminado");
    }

static void Main(){
 Task vs = Task.Run(() => DoWorkRobots());
        vs.Wait();
}
```

É mais ou menos isso que preciso, talvez precise de alguns ajustes e talvez ajude alguém por aqui também

Comment: Talvez seja interessante você tentar rodar todos ao mesmo tento utilizando um loop paralelo (Parallel.ForEach()). Caso não queria pesar no processamento, você pode tentar rodá-lo com baixa prioridade. Dessa forma você utiliza todos os cores de seu processador e sua tarefa não irá onerar o tanto o sistema.

Comment: Bem, questão é que não posso rodar todos no mesmo instante pois se trata de uma requisição SOAP e muitas podem sobrecarregar o WebService. Por isso preciso de um delay

Comment: Entendi o ponto. Uma sugestão: talvez seja interessante você tratar esse problema no próprio webservice, de modo que suporte mais requisições.

Comment: O webservice é de outra empresa, e foi criado faz tempo (uns 10 anos provavelmente) e não tem como ser alterado.